# Dissecting Report Metadata

Tags: metadata-api

What I want to do is pretty simple, but I can't seem to find a way to do it.
I need to take report metadata and extract from it:

- API names of objects from which the report extracts data
- API names of fields on that objects
- Applied filters

What I essentially need is to take a report and construct a set of SOQL queries that will pull from SFDC exactly the same data as the report.
It's more or less clear with custom fields:
[image: Custom Fields]

But when it comes to standard fields and objects, I'm at a loss, how do I extract actual API name of the field from those cryptic names (e.g. LEAD_OWNER)?
[image: Fields in metadata]

Comment: Some of those columns appear to be the label, upper-cased and with spaces replaced by underscores. In the case of LEAD_OWNER you could search the Lead fields for one with a matching label (post conversion). LEAD_OWNER_ALIAS and COMPANY_ACCT might be more difficult.

Comment: Yeah, and I don't like to rely on labels either, you can have to identical labels for different fields for all I know, although probably shouldn't happen with standard fields...